# Compressing big files into several files ubuntu

Tags: tar, zip, gzip

I am wondering if we on Ubuntu have an option to compress an directory of for instance 2GB size into several files that are restricted to the size of say 100 MB? I know on Microsoft Windows you can do this with some utilities such as WinZip (if I remember correctly).

However if I do it on Windows then file permissions/ownership are not kept, and when extracting in Ubuntu at a later point (several .z files) it often becomes corrupt.

I need to make the size of these files indented down to 100 MB or less due to upload restrictions (I am making a program that needs to download some big files).

It needs to be CLI based (or at least have a support for CLI extraction). This is for support on Ubuntu Servers.

Comment: `split`, check out `man split`.

Comment: That did indeed split into several 100MB files (`split test.tar -b 104857600`), however I am not sure if I am able to restore it to an .tar file again afterwards?

Comment: There is a `join` command for that. You will have to join the files and then hand this to `tar`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bzip2 and bunzip2 are file compression and decompression utilities.

> The bzip2 and bunzip2 utilities are newer than gzip and gunzip and are
>   not as common yet, but they are rapidly gaining popularity. The bzip2
>   utility is capable of greater compression ratios than gzip. Therefore,
>   a bzip2 file can be 10-20% smaller than a gzip version of the same
>   file. Usually,files that have been compressed by bzip2 will have a
>   .bz2 extension.<sup>1</sup>

To install, just press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> on your keyboard to open Terminal. When it opens, run the command(s) below:

```
sudo apt-get install bzip2
```

For more info, and how to use, you can take a look [here](http://www.debianadmin.com/create-and-extract-bz2-and-gz-files.html#more-155)

Note: I don't think that it will limit the size, but the compression is excellent.

Now you can also use WinRAR.  WinRAR is a powerful archive manager. It can backup your data and reduce the size of email attachments, decompress RAR, ZIP and other files.

To download and install click [here](http://www.techspot.com/downloads/5168-winrar-for-linux.html).  WinRAR will give you the option to create multivolume ZIP archives.

<sup><sup>**1**</sup>Source:[Debian Admin](http://www.debianadmin.com/create-and-extract-bz2-and-gz-files.html#more-155)</sup>

Comment: But am I able to restrict the size to 100MB for instance? So if when compressed it is a total of 700 MB then it would create 7 different files of 100MB?

Comment: I have updated my answer with that info.

Comment: Thank you! I should have added this in the original post (I did now, I forgot to do so), but it needs support for CLI extraction, more specifically Ubuntu Servers. EDIT: after doing a quick search, it seems to be doable through CLI, please edit answer if possible: http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1021185

Comment: There is old `split` and `join` and you want to install WinRAR on Ubuntu? And by the way, if you have a 2 GB raw data file, there is no way to compress it to a 100 MB.

Comment: Its a matter of preference, and he doesn't want to compress 2GB to 100MB, he wants to split the file to 100MMB parts.